# Should a guitar be de-tuned when not in use for long periods?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, guitar-effects

Should a guitar be de-tuned when not in use for long periods?

What are the possible damages could de-tuning do to my guitar?

Comment: It'll go detuned all on it's own :)

Comment: Detuning will not hurt your guitar.  Look in any guitar repair shop at the guitars that have no strings.  I stored a Yamaha FG100 acoustic folk guitar once for several years and failed to loosen the strings and the neck warped so badly from the string tension the truss rod was unable to pull it back straight enough to make the guitar playable!

Answer (score 0):

For most normal guitars, I have always been told not to do this.

A normal electric or steel-strung acoustic guitar will have a truss rod in the neck, and if adjusted correctly this will handle the string tension just fine.

For a truly traditional classical guitar with absolutely no neck reinforcement - I've never owned one.  If it will be stored for six months or more I would think about removing the strings, but I'd consult the maker first if possible...  For just a few months I would not bother, leave the strings on and under normal tension.